# Detect tags in textarea with key up event

Tags: regex, event-handling

I am want detect tags in selected text for change related tag button style

for this work i'm using key up event and send textArea content in tagController function for detect tags in selected  text

But it does not work properly....

patterns :

```
   var selMark = [
"\\[b\\](.*?)\\[\\/b\\]",
"\\[p\\](.*?)\\[\\/p\\]"
];
```

tagController plugin :

```
jQuery.fn.extend({

tagController : function(){

    if(document.selection){
            this.focus();
            sel = document.selection.createRange();

            for(i=0; i<selMark.length; i++){
             tag = selMark[i].substring(3,1).replace("[","").toUpperCase();
             if((new RegExp(selMark[i],"gi")).test(sel.text)){
                if(!$("input.tag[value="+tag+"]").hasClass('active')){
                $("input.tag[value="+tag+"]").addClass('active');
                }
             }else{
                $("input.tag[value="+tag+"]").removeClass('active');
                 }
            }
        }else if(this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0'){
            this.focus();
            var startPos = this.selectionStart, endPos = this.selectionEnd;
            sel = this.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
            for(i=0; i<selMark.length; i++){
             tag = selMark[i].substring(3,1).replace("[","").toUpperCase();
             if((new RegExp(selMark[i],"gi")).test(sel)){
                if(!$("input.tag[value="+tag+"]").hasClass('active')){
                $("input.tag[value="+tag+"]").addClass('active');
                }
             }else{
                $("input.tag[value="+tag+"]").removeClass('active');
                 }
            }
    }

    } });
```

usage :

```
$(function(){
 var source  = $('#txt');   
   source.keyup(function(){
     source.tagController();
     });
});
```

this section is for detect tags in patterns list and change button style

```
for(i=0; i<selMark.length; i++){
             tag = selMark[i].substring(3,1).replace("[","").toUpperCase();
             if((new RegExp(selMark[i],"gi")).test(sel)){
                if(!$("input.tag[value="+tag+"]").hasClass('active')){
                $("input.tag[value="+tag+"]").addClass('active');
                }
             }else{
                $("input.tag[value="+tag+"]").removeClass('active');
                 }
            }
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: When you say "It does not work properly" what do you mean? Can you expound?

Comment: Regular expressions are a very poor choice for this. They cannot actually handle the syntax used by a markup-tag language, because they have no way of "matching" tags: nested tags will be parsed incorrectly. If you only had simple text-formatting tags (`b`, `i`, etc), this wouldn't really be a problem, but if you want more complicated things (like `p`), it will not work.

Comment: @seangates i want change button style when find related tag in selected text with key up event
for example :
select : [b]test[/b]
change button style if it value is "b" , with key up event

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a rich text editor (RTE) like CLEditor (http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) or TinyMCE (http://www.tinymce.com/)?

Comment: I do not need an advanced editor 
and this editor easily work with ajax
can you help me for this problem?!

Comment: There is no suggestion or idea?!